# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, .net, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to get the html code of certain webpage,
I have a username and a password that are correct but i still can't get it to work,
this is my code:

```
private void buttondownloadfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NetworkCredentials nc = new NetworkCredentials("?", "?", "http://cdrs.globalpopsvoip.com/0000069/20091229/20091228_20091228.CDR");   
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.Credentials = nc;
    String htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://cdrs.globalpopsvoip.com/0000069/20091229/20091228_20091228.CDR");

    MessageBox.Show(htmlCode);
}
```

The MessageBox is just to test it,
the problem is that every time I get to this line:

```
String htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://cdrs.globalpopsvoip.com/0000069/20091229/20091228_20091228.CDR");
```

I get an exception:

> The remote server returned an error:
>   (401) Unauthorized.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 17):

In my case `client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

I have tried the following code and it is working.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)        
    {
        try
        {
            // Create Request
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://192.168.0.181/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?move=up");

            // Create Client
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            // Assign Credentials
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("root", "a");

            // Grab Data
            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(@"http://192.160.0.1/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?move=up");

            // Display Data
            MessageBox.Show(htmlCode);
        }
        catch (WebException ex) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to create a `NetworkCredential` without that domain part:

```
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("?", "?");
```